# Python regexp: exclude specific pattern from sub

Tags: python, regex

Having a string like this: `aa5f5 aa5f5` i try to split the tokens where non-digit meets digit, like this:

```
re.sub(r'([^\d])(\d{1})', r'\1 \2', 'aa5f5 aa5f5')

Out: aa 5f 5 aa 5f 5
```

Now i try to prevent some tokens from being splitted with specific prefix character($): `$aa5f5 aa5f5`, the desired output is `$aa5f5 aa 5f 5`

The problem is that i only came up with this ugly loop:

```
sentence = '$aa5f5 aa5f5'

new_sentence = []
for s in sentence.split():
    if s.startswith('$'):
        new_sentence.append(s)
    else:
        new_sentence.append(re.sub(r'([^\d])(\d{1})', r'\1 \2', s))

print(' '.join(new_sentence))  # $aa5f5 aa 5f 5
```

But could not find a way to make this possible with single line regexp. Need help with this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
new_sentence = re.sub(r'(\$\S*)|(?<=\D)\d', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else rf' {x.group()}', sentence)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KJJbwo).

Here, `(\$\S*)|(?<=\D)\d` matches `$` and any 0+ non-whitespace characters (with `(\$\S*)` capturing the value in Group 1, or a digit is matched that is preceded with a non-digit char (see `(?<=\D)\d` pattern part).

If Group 1 matched, it is pasted back as is (see `x.group(1) if x.group(1)` in the replacement), else, the space is inserted before the matched digit (see `else rf' {x.group()}'`).

With PyPi regex module, you may do it in a simple way:

```
import regex
sentence = '$aa5f5 aa5f5'
print( regex.sub(r'(?<!\$\S*)(?<=\D)(\d)', r' \1', sentence) )
```

See [this online Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqs4Na8kNS85VcFWQV0lMdE0zVQBTKpzFRRl5pVoQJTpFZcmaRSpa9jbKMaoxARraQJZtjEumhoxKZrqOgpF6goxhkAaZpimgub//wA).

The `(?<!\$\S*)(?<=\D)(\d)` pattern matches and captures into Group 1 any digit (`(\d)`) that is preceded with a non-digit (`(?<=\D)`) and not preceded with `$` and then any 0+ non-whitespace chars (`(?<!\$\S*)`).

Answer (score 1):

This is not something regular expression can do. If it can, it'll be a complex regex which will be hard to understand. And when a new developer joins your team, he will not understand it right away. It's better you write it the way you wrote it already. For the regex part, the following code will probably do the splitting correctly

```
' '.join(map(str.strip, re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', s)))
```

```
>>> s = "aa5f5 aa5f53r12"
>>> ' '.join(map(str.strip, re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', s)))
'aa 5 f 5 aa 5 f 53 r 12'
```